# How to find constraints for existing table?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, referential-integrity

How to find integrity constraints (such as primary key)
for an existing table? I am using Oracle 10g.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dictionary+oracle+primary+key&t=ffsb&yeg=B

Answer (score 1):

To find constraints on a table:

```
select constraint_name, constraint_type
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
```

There are matching dictionary views , ALL_ and DBA_, if you need to find constraints on tables in other schemas.

The four constraint types are

- **P** Primary key
- **U** Unique
- **R** Foreign key (reference)
- **C** Check

Check constraints include things which we don't immediately think of as constraints, such as NOT NULL.

So, to find the primary key on a table...

```
select constraint_name, constraint_type
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
and   c.constraint_type = 'P'
```

To find the table referenced in a foreign key:

```
select c.constraint_name as foreign_key
       , c.r_constraint_name as referenced_constraint
       , p.table_name
from user_constraints c
     join user_constraints p
      on p.constraint_name  = c.r_constraint_name 
where c.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
and   c.constraint_type = 'R'
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the data dictionary, specifically the USER_CONS_COLUMNS view to see the table columns and corresponding constraints:

```
SELECT *  FROM user_cons_columns WHERE table_name = '<your table name in caps>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It you are trying to find info about the data model, use a tool built for the job.

[Download SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)